# Using replace on string with random number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace the values for "min" and "max" price within the following URL string:

```
var url_full = "http://foo.com/?q=&min=0&max=789"

var url_clean = url_full.replace('&min='+ /\d+/,'');
var url_clean = url_full.replace('&max='+ /\d+/,'');
```

Struggling to replace the prices.

Comment: trying to replace values with what? empty? show inptu and output example

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `min` and `max` values with `''`

```js
var url_full = "http://foo.com/?q=&min=0&max=789&hellomin=350"

var url_clean = url_full.replace(/&min=\d+/,'&min=').replace(/&max=\d+/,'&max=')
   
console.log(url_clean);
```

Comment: What if they have another parameter in that string called `hellomin`? Might be useful to keep searching for the `&`.

Comment: Right! I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
> var url = new URL(window.location.href);
> url.searchParams.set('min','100'); window.location.href = url.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url_full = "http://foo.com/?q=&min=0&max=789"

var url_clean = url_full.replace('&min='+ /\d+/,'');
var url_clean = url_full.replace('&max='+ /\d+/,'');
console.log(url_clean);

var regex = /\d+/g;
var string = "http://foo.com/?q=&min=0&max=789";
var matches = string.match(regex);  // creates array from matches
for(var s=0;s<matches.length;s++){
console.log(matches[s]);
}
document.write(matches);
```

Use `regex` and `match` for finding digits.